# Are there any useful datasets available on the web for data mining?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-mining

Does anyone know any good resource where example (real) data can be downloaded for experimenting statistics and machine learning techniques such as decision trees etc?

Currently I am studying machine learning techniques and it would be very helpful to me to have real data for evaluating the accuracy of various tools.

If anyone knows of any good resource (perhaps as csv, xls files or any other format) I would be very thankful for a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UCI Machine Learning Archive](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) and the past datasets of the [KDD Cup](http://www.sigkdd.org/kddcup/index.php) are probably the best known such archives for general data mining. An example of a more specific kind of source is the [UCR Time Series Classification/Clustering Page](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an article from DataWrangling.com](http://www.datawrangling.com/some-datasets-available-on-the-web) that lists hundreds of datasets.

Answer (score 0):

On [Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com) you can find some competitions and download the associated datasets.

There is a system that scores your solutions in real time and you'll see your place on the "live leaderboard".

It's a good way of studying machine learning techniques because choosing a "for knowledge" competition you can compare your solution with other participants and discuss strengths and weaknesses of various approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try my blog, Vellum Information, where I've got several annotated bibliographies curating data sets and data sources:

http://velluminformation.com/2014/03/05/big-data-public-databases-an-annotated-bibliography/.

I've got an annotated bibliography of various data sources that are available. I've also got an annotated bibliography for health data here:

http://velluminformation.com/2012/05/19/free-online-public-data-sources-an-annotated-bibliography/.

Obvious disclosure, this is my blog, so there are other technical things on there as well.